# Error with scikit-learn.preprocessing: ImportError: No module named sklearn

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to normalize the values of an array to the range between `0` and `1`. I am running the code on `jupyter notebook` with `python 2`. I have already installed `scikit learn` , however, it is showing the following error:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn import preprocessing
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
f = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(f)
plt.imshow(f)
plt.show()

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-a856ee09a5a1> in <module>()
     28 
     29 #minmax scaling by scikit learn
---> 30 import sklearn
     31 from sklearn import preprocessing
     32 min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

Could someone please give some hints what is the reason?

Comment: are you sure that your notebook kernel is running on the same environment as the one where you installed sklearn?

Comment: @ChristianSauer Yes it is the same environment

Comment: can you check any sklearn* in directory of PATH-TO-/python-2.7.X/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ ?

Comment: Is there any other way to normalize the values of the array between 0 and 1?Unfortunately, I am not familiar with python packages and codes that much.

Comment: @ChristianSauer @caot Thanks for mentioning the point, I could solve it by exiting from the `conda` environment and reinstall it on anaconda. Thanks